# Passing php variable to smarty literal tags

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I am trying to pass a php variable to javascript in smarty literal tags.

So far, i tried

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = {/literal}{msg}{literal};
  window.onload = function () {
    alert(a);
}
</script>
{/literal}
```

which doesn't work. Any idea how can i make it work ?

Comment: I thought it went like this: `{$msg}` (and you might need to add literal quotes around it).

Comment: `var a = '<?php print $msg; ?>';`

Comment: Exact syntax might depend on how you're presenting the template. (You could post that and also any error messages involved in "doesn't work".)

Comment: @EthanB no error just blank page

Comment: Well then check the error logs to see what exactly you messed up in regards to smarty syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Just break it where ever you need it.
I have next situation that is working for me:

```
{literal}<script>var myArr = [];{/literal}
{foreach from=$myArr item=v}
    {if $v.title eq 'My Title'}
        {literal}var myArr.push({/literal}{$v.id}{literal});{/literal}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
{literal}</script>{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are missing and the $ sign is missing. Also, you don't really need to open {literal} before the script, just before the first '{' in the script, so things can look clearer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = '{$msg}';
{literal}
  window.onload = function () {
    alert(a);
}
</script>
{/literal}
```